# Performance Issue - Select firstdate per month on a very big table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, row-number

I have a very big table (over 140 mil of rows and size of around 230 gb). There is a column, called "date_dim" with a clustered index asc. In the table are stored all data from 2015.

My target is now to get the first date of a month that data are stored. So it could be that in January the data started at the 5th. So I have to build a 'dynamic' query.

To retrieve this data, I created following query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
  SELECT               
    date_dim
    ,row_num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH(date_dim) ORDER BY date_dim ASC)
   FROM myTable_2015 WITH (NOLOCK)
 ) AS s
WHERE
    row_num = 1
ORDER BY
    1
```

Now my Issue is that the query has a very long time to get the data. Is there maybe an other option to build a query with better performance ? Do you have any Performance advise for selecting such big tables for my specific case ?

Actually I cannot make any changes on the table itself, only 'Read' Access...

Comment: Cant you just get it from the Date table?

Comment: No, because I need the first date that data is stored per month...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, two quick options

```
Select BOMonth = min(date_dim)
 From  myTable_2015 
 Group By year(date_dim),month(date_dim)
```

Or even

```
Select BOMonth = min(date_dim)
 From  (select distinct date_dim from myTable_2015 ) A
 Group By year(date_dim),month(date_dim)
```

Comment: The second query should be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use a window function:

```
SELECT distinct min([date_dim]) 
     over (partition by Year([date_dim]), month([date_dim])) as [FirstDate]
FROM myTable_2015
ORDER BY [date_dim]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 140 mil rows then good chance you have the first of every month

```
select distinct(date_dim) 
from   myTable_2015 WITH (NOLOCK)
where  day(date_dim) = 1
```

Or you could isolate on the first x

```
select min(date_dim) 
from   myTable_2015 WITH (NOLOCK)
where  day(date_dim) <=5 
group by month(date_dim)
```